# Passwordless SSH (Windows --> CentOS)

Tags: ssh, centos

I am trying to get passwordless SSH authentication to work from a Windows 7 machine to local server.

1. Windows machine: My login name in this machine is `MY_LOGIN_NAME`. I am using Cygwin as the command line.
2. CentOS 5.5 Server: I have admin privileges on this server; logged in as `root`.

Here is what I have done so far:

1. Logged into `MY_LOGIN_NAME` on the Windows machine, I `ssh-config-user`ed from the Cygwin command line. This created  (at least) RSA public and private keys in     `C:/Users/MY_LOGIN_NAME/.ssh`
2. I copied the public key over to the server to the `.ssh` directory using `scp`.

   scp id-rsa.pub root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx:.ssh/id-rsa.pub
3. Then I tried to log into the server using `ssh` like so:

   ssh -i id_rsa root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx

But it still asks me for my password. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is your step 2. You overwrote root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx public key with your Cygwin public key. That's not what you want.

You should, instead, add your public key to root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx authorized keys. This can be done manually appending your id-rsa.pub to /root/.ssh/autorized_keys (on CentOS), or automagically running *ssh-copy-id* on Cygwin.

```
ssh-copy-id root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx
```

It will prompt for your password and then you should be fine.

Also, you should recover root@xxx.xxx.xx.xx public key, or generate a new pair, if it's not inconvenient.

Comment: Please note that even with the proper keys in place, unless the client side is running an ssh-agent with the appropriate key loaded, an ssh connection attempt will prompt for password/passphrase (of course, that is unless prohibited by some other configuration values).

Answer (score 1):

Also, be aware of the **PermitRootLogin** option available in the server-side /etc/ssh/sshd_config file, which is described,

```
PermitRootLogin
Specifies whether root can log in using ssh(1). The argument must be "yes",
"without-password", "forced-commands-only", or "no". The default is "yes".

If this option is set to "without-password", password authentication is
disabled for root.
```

Setting it to "without-password" has the effect of only allowing root to log in through ssh by having an authorized public key in place, which keeps [Mallory](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BuUSi_QvFLY) from attempting to brute-force root's password. However, failure to authenticate via authorized public key manifests as repeated password prompts, which can be confusing.